# Redirect all pages to the custom login page except for the registration page

Tags: customization, redirect, login, user-registration

I have redirected all non logged in users to my login page but on the page there is an option for them to register and that navigates back to my login page and I want to exclude that register page from my login page. Can someone please advise?

This is my code:

```
function admin_redirect() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 12019 )) {
       wp_redirect( home_url('member-login') );
       exit;
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

Comment: If you plan to deal with redirection on page load use the `template_redirect` event, instead of `get_header`

Comment: Is registration a separate page or is it the same page but with a parameter in the URL?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a plugin to do this, I suggest you to use the "User Registration" plugin
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there maybe a way to do it without a plugin?